# resource.get({id:1}, callback).$promise undefined in Angular 1.2.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```js
service = $resource('api/data/:id/', {
    id: '@id',
}, 'get': {
    method: 'GET',
    isArray: false
});
```

When I request something like that:

```js
var promise = service.get({id:1}, callback).$promise
```

… the value of the `$promise` object is undefined. What is wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

When you refer the `$promise` object at such stage, it is an empty reference.

From the [docs on `$resource`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource):

> It is important to realize that invoking a `$resource` object method
>   immediately returns an empty reference […] Once the data is returned 
>   from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data

The behavior of the `$promise` object at the stage of resource invocation is undefined (no pun intended):

> - **`$promise`**: the promise of the original server interaction that created
>     this instance or collection.
>
>   On success, the promise is resolved with the same resource instance or
>     collection object, updated with data from server. […]
>
>   On failure, the promise is resolved with the http response object,
>     without the resource property.

If you meant to act on the populated data, call the instance action methods in the callback. This is how it's done:

```js
var p = service.get({id:1}, function() {
    p.$save(); // some action method on the instance e.g. $save
});
```